# Async function await not waiting

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an async function that I am using to query mysql database in Node.js. I am waiting for the result of the query execution and inserting the result into an array.

```
  async function getOpenOrders() {
    try {
        const arrayLoads = [],
            last4Orders = await pool.query( `${query1} ` )
        // console.log(last4Orders)
        for ( let i = 0; i < last4Orders.length; i++ ) {
            // console.log(last4Orders[i].orderID)
            console.log( arrayLoads )
            console.log( `===================` )
            const rows = await pool.query( `${query2}` )
            console.log( rows )
            arrayLoads.push( rows )
            // console.log(arrayLoads)
        }
        // console.log(rows[0])
        // console.log(arrayLoads)
        res.send( arrayLoads )
    } catch ( err ) {
        console.log( err )
    }
}

getOpenOrders()
```

However, the await query inside the for loop is not stopping the sync code because my `console.log()` displays something like:

```
    []
    ===================
    []
    [ [] ]
    ===================
    []
    [ [], [] ]
    ===================
    [RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 },
      RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 }]
[ [],
  [],
[RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 },
      RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 }]
===================
[RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 },
      RowDataPacket { Number: '4732', Test: 'TQLM-384', User: 23 }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql `pool.query` method returns a callback, if you want to use `async await`, try to promisify the method and then use `async await`

```
 const {promisify} = require('util');
    async function getOpenOrders() {
        try {
            const arrayLoads = [],
                query = promisify(pool.query).bind(pool);
                last4Orders = await query( `${query1} ` )
            // console.log(last4Orders)
            for ( let i = 0; i < last4Orders.length; i++ ) {
                // console.log(last4Orders[i].orderID)
                console.log( arrayLoads )
                console.log( `===================` )
                const rows = await query( `${query2}` )
                console.log( rows )
                arrayLoads.push( rows )
                // console.log(arrayLoads)
            }
            // console.log(rows[0])
            // console.log(arrayLoads)
            res.send( arrayLoads )
        } catch ( err ) {
            console.log( err )
        }
    }

    getOpenOrders()
```

Comment: My pool is already promisified. My issue was that the result of 2 out of 4 queries resulted in an empty array and I thought that the await code was not working.